# jquery multiple ajax calls without using asynch false

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a page that has to run an ajax command a few times.  It has to use the results of the previous ajax call in for the current one.

in laymen's terms:

call ajax, build entity on remote server, return result (i get a proprietary id as result)
...

call ajax, use result to post additional data to remote server, get id of this post
...

call ajax, post ids..etc

my first idea was async:false, but i see this is widely unacceptable and it ruins code execution order. My goal too, is to have a dialog window that prints the results of the ajax calls as they happen.  Currently, the dialog window appears once all ajax calls are done.  I don't get the pretty little:  Build....done  then additional Options.....done  and so on...

if i make asynch:true, i wont have the id's need to process the next ajax..

what other options do i have have?

```
//form var is set earlier, standard serialized form.

  var functions = ['build','additionalOptions','completion'];

$('#submitButton').click(function(){

    $('#createGroupDialog').dialog({
        autoOpen:false,
        width: 1200,
        height:800,

        modal: true,
        position: {my: "top", at: "top"},
        resizable: false,
        closeOnEscape: true
       });

    $("#createGroupDialog").dialog('open').html("<p>Please Wait...</p>");

   function fireAjax(form,func)
    {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "createGroup/createGroupDo.php",
            data: form+"&func="+func,
            asynch: false,
            success: function (result) {
                            $('#createGroupDialog').append(result);
            }
            });
    }

    jQuery.each(functions , function(i,func){
            fireAjax(form,func);
    });

});
```

Comment: Take a look at `.promise()` objects. I think they should accomplish what you are looking for...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`asynch:false` is indeed a terrible way to deal with asynchronous data. It doesn't mess with the  execution order but it *blocks* until the request finishes meaning no other JavaScript can run in the mean time, this includes things like `onclick` handlers and animations.

Since your requests rely on a previous request you have to write them like that:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "request1.php",
    data: data,
    success: function (result_1) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "request2.php",
            data: result_1,
            success: function (result_2) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "request3.php",
                    data: result_2,
                    success: function () {}
                });
            });
        }); 
    }
});
```

But as you can see this gets tedious. You *can* use callbacks, but it's better use the `Promise` API.

Use like:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "request1.php",
    data: data
}).then(function (result_1) {
    alert(result_1);
    return $.ajax({
        url: "request2.php",
        data: result_1,
    }); 
}).then(function (result_2) {
    alert(result_2);
    return $.ajax({
        url: "request3.php",
        data: result_2
    });
}).then(function (result_3) {
    alert(result_3);
});
```

It's worth noting that jQuery does a lot of work under the hood to make this API possible. `$.ajax` is a very flexible function. This means you can use it in many ways. It's best to chose one way and to stick with it. The current state of art really leans towards Promises.